# PHP - Output Specific Line from Array

Tags: php, chargify

I'm using a form to collect payments and using print_r, I can see the following in the output...

```
[customer] => ChargifyCustomer Object
    (
        [email] => test@aol.com
        [first_name] => John
        [last_name] => Doe
        [organization] => 
        [reference] => 
        [id] => 2588487
        [created_at] => 2012-12-14T08:50:45-05:00
        [updated_at] => 2012-12-14T08:50:45-05:00
    )
```

The PHP to produce this output is seen below...

```
try {
    $new_subscription = $subscription->create();
    if ($new_subscription != '') {
        // session_unset();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($new_subscription);
        echo '</pre>';
        foreach ($new_subscription as $item) {
            echo 'First Name' . $item->customer->first_name . '.';
        }
    }
}
```

Though every time I load the page, the first name is not being echoed. Instead, it just says 'First Name.' several times.

Please help out to determine where my error is.

Comment: why don't you try `print_r($item)` inside the `foreach` loop and see what it looks like. I guess you're almost there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the key:

```
foreach($new_subscription as $key => $item) {
    if($key == 'first_name') {
        echo "First Name: " . $item . '.';
    }
}
```

But I don't know why you would do a foreach since $new_subscription is not an array of objects. In reality you should just say:

```
echo "First Name: " . $new_subscription->first_name. '.';
```

Comment: `$new_subscription['customer']->first_name` instead of `$new_subscription->first_name`

Comment: He should have copied the entire print_r, if it were actually an array it would have started out as: `Array ( [customer] => ChargifyCustomer Object ...`